# Why are the 1-skeleton graphs of the Regular Polytopes distance transitive?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, graph-theory, platonic-solids

A graph $G$ is distance transitive if for all vertices $u,v,w,x$ of $G$ such that $D_G(u,v) = D_G(w,x) $ implies that there exists a graph automorphism of $G$, $\psi \in \Gamma(G)$ such that $\psi(u) = w$, $\, \psi(v) = x$.

If we have a regular polytope, $\mathcal{P}$, (spherical, euclidean or hyperbolic) then if we take the graph whose vertices are the vertices of $\mathcal{P}$ and whose vertices are adjacent if and only if they share an edge in $\mathcal{P}$.

I should be clear that I do NOT know that this s true for all regular polytopes. But checking the few I can they seem to be so.

Comment: Regular polytopes are vertex-transitive, so we know that we can always move $u$ to $w$ via some automorphism. Therefore, the problem would seem to reduce to this: *Given some vertex $u$ and some distance $d$, does the set of vertices at distance $d$ from $u$ form (a subset of) an orbit under the sub-group of automorphisms that fix $u$?*

Comment: Check more. The 120-cell and the 600-cell in $\mathbb{R}^4$ are not distance transitive. If memory serves, they are not even distance regular.

Comment: I just checked the 120-cell. It is indeed not distance regular or distance transitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Chris Godsil in the comments, not all Platonic solids are distance-transitive: the 24-cell, 120-cell ans 600-cell are *not* distance-transitive.

Here is a complete list of polytopes that are distance-transitive (i.e. not only their edge-graph is distance-transitive, but also their Euclidean symmetry group acts distance-transitively on the skeleton):

- regular polygons,
- the regular dodecahedron and regular icosahedron,
- the $d$-dimensional [crosspolytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope),
- cartesian powers of regular simplices (this includes, of course, the regular simplices, but also the regular $d$-dimensional cube as the power $[0,1]\times\cdots\times[0,1]$),
- [hyper-simplices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersimplex),
- [demi-cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demihypercube),
- the [$2_{21}$-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_21_polytope),
- the [$3_{21}$-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_21_polytope).

See also Theorem 5.10 in my recent preprint:

- [M. Winter, "Eigenpolytopes, Spectral Polytopes and Edge-Transitivity." arXiv preprint arXiv:2009.02179 (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.02179).

However, the true reason for why exactly those polytopes are distance-transitive is more complicated. Chris Godsil should indeed be the perfect person to explain this, as it was essentially proven in his paper

- C.D. Godsil, "Eigenpolytopes of distance regular graphs." Canadian Journal of Mathematics 50.4 (1998): 739-755.